# Visual Studio 2010 "Cannot create window" error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I launch Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, I get the error "Cannot create window". Do you know of any solutions?

Answer (score 10):

In my case, it was installing IBM Client Access v6.1 service pack SI37891. When it installed the .NET 4 data provider it broke the XML file.

The file in question can be found here:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

An additional data provider was installed and a spurious XML close tag was added incorrectly:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
<add name="IBM DB2 for i5/OS .NET Provider" ...... /></DbProviderFactories>
<add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" ....../>
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Comment: Thank you!  One more stinking joy in the upgrade to V6R1, but at least you saved me a ton of searching!

Comment: Dude, if I could, I would give you +100. Thank you!

Comment: There was two files I had to edit.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\machine.config
and
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Answer (score 1):

if you install and remove netframework 4.5 maybe it happens, reinstall the netframework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Rename msvcm100.dll to msvcm100.dll.old in c:\windows\system32
2. Run Visual Studio 2010 repair and msvcm100.dll should get recreated.

Source:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/458377/cannot-create-the-window-dialog-appears-during-vs-2010-startup

Comment: there is not msvcm100.dll in my folder c:\windows\system32

Comment: I personally haven't yet this problem thankfully, but from what it seems is to be a problem after installing Office 2010?  Have you recently done that?  Also, have you tried running Visual Studio 2010 repair to see if it fixes your issue?

Comment: About two month ago I had installed office 2010 and then I delete it. Ok, I'll try to repair vs 2010

Comment: I'm been getting the same problems with VS2010 RTM and haven't gone anywhere near Office 2010. Also no msvcm100.dll in my System32 folder.

Comment: I would just love to point out that suddenly every answer except for vasmt's is downvoted..

Comment: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\  in 64 bits machines

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me today for the first time while using VS2010 premium on Windows 7. The only thing different since the last time I used it (16hrs ago) was Windows Update which the System Restore utility says only affected an unrelated local app on my machine, Grooveshark.

Anyway, I restored to the point created immediately before the update, and VS2010 doesn't complain about not being able to "Create Window" anymore... don't think this was related to a recent Resharper 5 install.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found that my machine.config file was not editable.  I couldn't even open it to look at it. I'm not sure why. I ended up uninstalling .NET framework 4.5 and re-installing .NET framework 4.0. I was also having trouble with Visual Studio 2012. I'm re-installing that now to see if that works. For the record, I have IBM System i Access for Windows installed on my machine. That may have caused the problem to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when attempting to start up `SQL Server Management Studio 2012`. Cleaning out the following folders fixed it:

- `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\`
- `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\`
- `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Temp\`
- `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Windows\Temp\`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, inspecting the Event Viewer, I discovered an "Error 1704. An installation for Microsoft .NET Framework is currently suspended".

So the solution was running Windows Update and installing the pending update for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i made same C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

So had to delete the double tags of DbProviderFactories that i had in file.

Answer (score 0):

Run "Visual Studio Installer" and click repair on the affected VS version.