# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: Error while opening

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

On SQL Server 2014, when I open SQL Server Management Studio I get the following error message:

> Cannot create the window

When running it as Administrator the application opens without error.

Has anyone seen this before and why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: When I open as administrator I'm able to use the application without any errors. I'm able to modify stored procedures and triggers.

Comment: So then just use it as administrator in the future?  .......

Comment: Correct I've proceed to use it as administrator, but still this isn't my environment so I need to provide feedback on why this is happening and it's not working as normal.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672860/visual-studio-2010-cannot-create-window-error - different application, but maybe the same issue

Comment: Thanks Jen R, I'm reviewing if any of the solutions provided there solve my particular issue. But definitely sounds like it may be related.

Comment: Getting this with SQL Server Management Studio 17.7 even after a repair install :(