# "Cannot create the window" with visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to open visual studio 2013 but there is getting popup with "Cannot create the window".

[image]

I search on google there was solution with VS2010 and I'm applied those changes(Rename machine.config to machine.config.default) and repair vs2013 as well but issue is still exist.

Please provide me if any appropriate solution is available.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Safe Mode https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/11/15/visual-studio-safe-mode

Comment: I tried same solution but problem is still there.

Comment: Anything from here helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672860/visual-studio-2010-cannot-create-window-error

Comment: My machine have installed both vs2010 and vs2013 where vs2010 is working fine and issue with vs2013. Is there any solution vs2013 specific?

Comment: Look at update history and event log for errors or hints.

Comment: No update history are there and may I know for event log you're talking about event viewer?

Comment: I was referring to Windows update and Windows events.

Comment: There is no logs and no history related to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132272/discussion-between-mukesh-dutt-and-jeffrson).

Comment: Sorry, no more ideas